# near/far jmp/call specifics

Tags: assembly, x86, real-mode, memory-segmentation

I can't get full grip on specifics of far/near versions of jmp/call. As I understand near jmp/call instructions use relative offset from instruction itself as operand. Far jmp/call instructions use absolute address as operand.

1) In protected mode this absolute address is just virtual address placed by the compiler.
2) In real mode you usually write:

```
jmp [new number of code segment][proc name as offset]
```

then absolute address is computed by formula:

```
address = new number * 10h + offset
```

which is really physical address in real mode.

**Does CPU automatically update CS when performing far jmp/call?** For example when BIOS code jumps to loaded boot sector code. I don't see setting CS value in source code of boot sector file.

In protected mode: `cs = index in descriptor table = absolute address / page size`
In real mode: `cs = segment index in RAM = specified "new number of code segment"`

Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the far jump/call updates `CS` of course.

In protected mode, the segment selector refers to an entry in a table, namely the `GDT` (global descriptor table) or the `LDT` (local descriptor table) depending on the value of bit #2. Said descriptor entry holds the base address and the limit for the segment.

This is all described in detail in the intel manuals.